# Multiple Indices

Tags: indexing

I am trying to write a report with multiple indices. One index for keywords, and another index for authors.

Despite extensive search on the Internet, I have not found any single working example.

Can you provide any **complete** example that works? I would using the package imakeidx, but I do not care whatever package you use as long as it actually works.

Comment: Package imakeidx -- very easy!

Comment: @cmhughes: Go ahead ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, here's a complete MWE, compile it using `shell escape`, e.g

```
pdflatex   --shell-escape   "mult-indexes.tex"
```

or, otherwise, simply have [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) do the lifting

```
arara mult-indexes.tex
```

It uses the [`imakeidx`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/imakeidx) package.

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: on}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}

% index stuff
% index stuff
% index stuff
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=practice,title=Practice -- what do we do]
\makeindex[name=knowledge,title=Knowledge -- what we need to know]
\makeindex[name=values,title=Values -- being professional]
\makeindex[name=assessment,title=Assessment criteria]

\begin{document}

here is some text

\index[practice]{cmh}
\index[knowledge]{shuhalo}
\index[values]{something}
\index[assessment]{else}

\printindex[practice]
\printindex[knowledge]
\printindex[values]
\printindex[assessment]

\end{document}
```